# How is ground speed simulated for an accelerating vehicle?

Tags: torque, moment-of-inertia

[image]

For vehicles on "treadmills", how is the ground simulated by the drum (as depicted) to *accurately* represent the energy loss to drag.

I have been conceptualizing the process below, but am skeptical of the results.

---

$F_{drag}$ is the force equivalent to drag and wheel resistance acting on the vehicle as a function of velocity.

$F_{drag}$ $*$ $r_{drum}$ = $\tau_{drag}$

If I understand correctly, the $\tau_{drag}$ makes sure the drum slows to a stop at the same rate the vehicle would slow to a stop from $F_{drag}$ above.  Braking or accelerating would create a net torque that would have to be addressed in the system.

---

$\tau_{net} =  \tau_{motor} - \tau_{drag} + \tau_{friction} + \tau_{drum}$

$\tau_{friction}$ $\Rightarrow$ 
Some rotational energy is lost to friction in the rotating parts that are not present in the ground.

$\tau_{drum}$ $\Rightarrow$ 
The rotating drum has rotational energy that *assists* the Top wheel when accelerating, *opposes* the top wheel's decrease in speed during deceleration (negative a, positive v), and is zero when the drum and top are rotating at the same $\omega$.

$\tau_{drum} = I_{drum} * \alpha$

$\alpha = a_{veh}/r_{drum}$

$I_{drum} = ???$ $\Rightarrow$ The moment of inertia of the drums, somewhere between $mr^2$ and $1/2*mr^2$

Alpha's direction flips the sign between + and - necessary to address the assistance, opposition, or no net effect mentioned above.

Finally,

$\tau_{motor}$ $\Rightarrow$
The motor must supply whatever difference is necessary to balance the equation:

$\tau_{net} =  \tau_{motor} - \tau_{drag} + \tau_{friction} + \tau_{drum}$

---

The $\tau_{motor}$ should be controllable, leaving $I_{drum}$ as the major remaining hurdle.  **What noticeable defects are apparent in my thought process for simulating the ground under an accelerating vehicle?**

Disclaimer:  I have been able to guess a value for $\tau_{drum}$ but I do not understand how the value that works is possible.

Comment: Do you want to simulate vehicle drag such that your simulation matches a real automobile?  If so, note that real automobiles experience air drag, which varies with velocity squared, so your treadmill data will be missing important information.

Comment: Yes, I would like the simulation to match what a vehicle would experience on level ground. The Fdrag function in the problem includes the air drag. The treadmill measures velocity rapidly and updates the Fdrag value with each new input.